# INFOPATH 2013 - SHOW/HIDE FIELDS ACCORDING TO CALENDAR MONTH

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, custom-form

I am looking for some help with this one.

I have a form which is for an employee award. The voting takes place within the calendar month. I need a conditional rule which will toggle between my sections - aligning these sections to the month.

I am familiar with creating conditional rules - I need to know how to create the logic for the toggle between calendar months.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer that may help out someone else.

The solution I was looking for was to find the current month and use this to toggle between messages.

Basic form display example below - date display field is hidden:
[image]
Basic form display example below - date display field is viewable:
[image]
Expression used for field1:

substring-before(substring-after(today(), "-"), "-")

[image]
[image]
Currently two sections created

*for my purpose there would be 12 sections with corresponding display messages and from details
I am using default **Title** field, **field1**, **field2** & **field3**

[image]

Section rule - conditions:

Section 1 - Displays if the date is third month

Section 1 contains a text field message

Section 2 - Displays if the date is not third month

Section 2 contains a text field message

[image]
[image]

Toggle achieved. For the remaining months of the year the I will add to the rules and conditions.

I am sure there is a better way to do this but it gives me the result I need.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following:

1.Choose the field and click Manage rules, create a new formatting rule.

2.In the condition, set the condition you want.

3.In the formatting, choose "Hide this control".

[image]

Comment: I am familiar with creating rules - what I am looking for is specific help around how to create the logic within the rule for calendar months.